# ajax not submitting form

Tags: javascript, ajax, file-upload

I'm working on a file sharing service. However I ran into an issue. For some reason file is being selected however AJAX is not reading this selection and is not automatically uploading the file. And thus to this response is not being processed back and inserted into a DIV on the page.

**HTML + FORM**

```
        <div class="file-input-wrapper"> 
          <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.xml">
          <button class="btn-file-input" id="bt">Select a File to Share</button>
          <input type="file" name="file" multiple />
          </form>
          <br/><br/>
          <div id="response"></div>
         </div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
(function () {
    var input = document.getElementById("file"),
        formdata = false;

    function showUploadedItem(source) {
        document.getElementById("image-list").innerHTML = "<li><img src='" + source + "' /></li>";
    }

    if (window.FormData) {
       formdata = new FormData();
       document.getElementById("bt").style.display = "inline";
    }

    input.addEventListener("change", function (evt) {
        document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "<div class='uploading'></div>"
        var i = 0,
            len = this.files.length,
            img, reader, file;
        formdata = new FormData();
        //for ( ; i < len; i++ ) {
        file = this.files[i];

        if (file.type.match(/file.*/)) {
            if (window.FileReader) {
                reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onloadend = function (e) {
                    var source = e.target.result;
                    document.getElementById("image-list").innerHTML = "<li><img src='" + source + "' /></li>";
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }
            if (formdata) {
                formdata.append("file[]", file);
            }
        }
        //}

        if (formdata) {
            $.ajax({
                    url: "upload.xml",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: formdata,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    success: function (res) {
                        document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = res;
                    }
                });
        }
    }, false);
})();
```

The code originally worked however when I tried to style the file input filed this is when hell broke loose and things broke, and at this point i'm not sure what im doing wrong.

You can also take a look at the code live at this URL: cyogen.com

Comment: What is your question?  The code above looks fine and the page you have looked to seems to work fine as well.

Comment: Im not sure if it was you who down voted but if you cared to take a closer look at source its not the same as above, thats because i fixed it. This is added after file input  <button type="submit" id="btn" style="display:none;"></button>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because your id is "bt" not "btn". At this line:

```
document.getElementById("btn").style.display = "none";
```

Comment: That would not make a difference, i changed it to "bt" and it simply hidden the button. Clicking the empty section where the button was will still fire up the file input, however selecting file will not result in an upload.

Comment: I updated the code to document.getElementById("bt").style.display = "inline"; still the same problem as before

Comment: This caused the script to halt in Chrome but there may be an error elsewhere.

Comment: Huh that is strange, im testing it in Chrome latest build "Version 27.0.1453.110" haven't had any issues of any sort with the speed.

Comment: Are you looking in the browser's console? There is now a similar error because "file" is a name, not an id. Hint: "file" can be both the name and the id of the input.

Comment: Here is the working code, i changed the values to what they where before "images" http://cyogen.com/index-0.html

Comment: Actually i might have gotten it working, for some reason the submit class is required

Comment: Ah! Please don't correct the code in your original post. It will be extremely confusing for someone who reads this thread in the future.